# Printing to Console in scalding script

Tags: scala, sbt, scalding

I am trying to display some content on the console in a scalding script. When I run the same logic in the scalding shell I get the desired output and when I run the script I get an error:
scripttest.scala:4: error: value dump is not a member of com.twitter.scalding.typed.TypedPipe[String]

The script is

```
 import com.twitter.scalding._
 class scripttest(args:Args) extends Job(args){
 val hello = TypedPipe.from(TextLine("tutorial/data/hello.txt"))
 hello.dump
 }
```

When I ran the same logic in console, it ran successfully.
The output in console:
Hello world 
Goodbye world

Please explain why this occurs and how to print to console in a scalding script.

Answer (score 2):

After looking closely at the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/scalding/readthedocs/scalding.pdf), you will see in section "2.6 REPL Reference", subsection "2.6.1 Enrichments available on TypedPipe/Grouped/CoGrouped objects" :

> .dump: Print the contents to stdout (uses .toIterator)

hence `dump` is available *only* in the REPL.

I don't see a "scalding way" to write on the console, nor do I think it would make sense: you are running a pipeline, so the only "guaranteed milestone" is the end of the pipeline, when you can just `write` your results into a file, as is done on all the [tutorial scripts](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/tree/develop/tutorial).

If it's just a matter of printing "hello my job started", remember it's just a Scala file and use `println` (for more advanced logging, [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) is your friend).

To run the script locally, after having cloned the repository:

```
> ./sbt assembly
> ./scripts/scald.rb --local MyScript.scala
```

The first line will run all tests and build "scald.rb", the script used in the second line to run your scalding script.

Comment: I need to see the intermediate contents of a pipe to write test cases for this case.

Comment: You might be looking for "snapshots" in the REPL. They have a dedicated subsection in section "1.1.2 Scalding REPL" of the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/scalding/readthedocs/scalding.pdf) - or you can also look [here](https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Scalding-REPL).  An alternative would be, in your script, to cut your pipeline after the point where you want to see the data (aka comment part of the code) and `write` it in a file.

Comment: Thanks This is exactly What I was looking for

Comment: Cool. If it answers your question feel free to accept it. Cheers